# Loop throught list in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I am new to R. Get stuck in my homework:

1. Create a list with length 10: for the first component list[[1]], the
   dimension is 1, the second is 1*2, the third is 3*3, the fourth is
   4*4, and so on. The values should be selected randomly from 1:100.
2. For each component in the list, select the values > 50 and write a
   function to calculate a value = sd (values)/mean(values) when
   length(values)>1, otherwise return 0.

my code is :

```
v1 = c(runif(1,1,100))
v2 = matrix(runif(2,1,100))
v3 = matrix(runif(9,1,100),3,3)
v4 = matrix(runif(16,1,100),4,4)
li = list(v1,v2,v3,v4)
for (i in li){
  if (li[[i]] >5){
    print (li[[i]])
  }
}
```

but it seems like there is somthing wrong with my for loop, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an answer to part 1. With R, there are usually multiple ways of accomplishing the same task. When I first started, I was lost. But by working through and struggling with the hw, I learned so much.

```
lst <- list()
for(i in 1:10) lst[[i]] <- sample(100,i^2)
lst
```

A little bit about the code: An empty list is created on the outside of the loop. Think about why it can't be on the inside.

I can give the counter variable a name, I chose arbitrarily, `i`. We pick from the whole number set 1 through 100. The first time around, we pick 1 squared numbers. Which is equal to `1`. The second round we pick 2 squared numbers from 1 to 100, which is 4. And so on.

**Update:**

Since you've had time to try part 2, here's some help. `lst2` is a subset of `lst` with only values greater than 50. The intuitive move is to run `lst > 50` or `lst[lst > 50]`. These are misleading routes. Use the `lapply` function to evaluate the function to each list element.

```
lst2 <- lapply(lst, function(x) x[x>50])
```

Next, we create a function with the constraints in the question. The function `ifelse` is quick and easy in this case.

```
f <- function(x) {
  ifelse(length(x) > 1, sd(x)/mean(x), 0)
}
```

And lastly, we run the function that we defined above. We use the same `lapply` function to complete the task.

```
lapply(lst2, f)
```

**Summary**

The whole assignment can be done with:

```
lst <- list()
for(i in 1:10) lst[[i]] <- sample(100,i^2)
lst2 <- lapply(lst, function(x) x[x>50])
f <- function(x) ifelse(length(x) > 1, sd(x)/mean(x), 0) 
lapply(lst2, f)
```

Comment: thanks! the code is very clean, but do you know how to solve the part2?

Comment: The best way to give thanks for an answer is to click the v-shaped checkmark next to my answer to accept the answer.